# AS3: cant acess method goToAndStop from package

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

In my Main FLA file`s library I have a movieclip which is named ProgressBar and AS linkage is also defined as ProgressBar.

Then I created ProgressBar.as file. see below. When i use this class, I get the error `ProgressBar.as, Line 17  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method goToAndStop through a reference with static type ProgressBar.`

**USAGE:**

```
var PBar:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
addChild(PBar);
PBar.setProgress(10); // gives Error
```

**ProgressBar.as**

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class ProgressBar extends MovieClip
    {
        private var movie:MovieClip;
        public function ProgressBar() {
            //set initial position
            setPosition(400,400);
        }
        public function setPosition(X:Number,Y:Number):void{
             this.x=X;
             this.y=Y;
        }
        public function setProgress(value:Number):void{
              var progress = Math.round(value); 
              this.goToAndStop(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `goto` has to be all lowercase, ie `gotoAndStop()` instead of `goToAndStop()`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop()